# Android source build arm-eabi-gcc not found

Tags: android, gcc, arm, eabi

When building android source I get the error arm-eabi-gcc not found in path. I downloaded the prebuilt binaries from the android website and added the bin directory in my path. I've ensured arm-eabi-gcc is in path. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ccache wasn't setup properly. Stopped using ccache and build works fine. Will have to add back after doing some more research on ccache.